# How to create pipeline for Neural Network models?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning

I have tried creating a pipeline like this but I am getting error

*- AttributeError: 'Pipeline' object has no attribute 'compile'*

```
scaler = StandardScaler()
model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(120, input_dim=46,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.1, noise_shape=None, seed=None))

model.add(Dense(80, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.1, noise_shape=None, seed=None))

model.add(Dense(40, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

pipeline = make_pipeline(scaler,model)
pipeline.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])


pipeline.fit(X_train,y_train, epochs=50, batch_size=20, validation_data = (X_test,y_test))

# evaluate the model
scores = pipeline.evaluate(X_test,y_test)
print("\n%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100))
```

Comment: may i know the reason for down vote ?

Answer (score 1):

I am able to achieve this with below code

Thanks  @JahKnows

```
scaler = StandardScaler()
model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(120, input_dim=46,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.1, noise_shape=None, seed=None))

model.add(Dense(80, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.1, noise_shape=None, seed=None))

model.add(Dense(40, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

pipeline = Pipeline([("scaler",scaler),("model",model)])
pipeline.fit(X_train,y_train, model__epochs=50, model__batch_size=20, model__validation_data = (X_test,y_test))

# evaluate the model
nn_pred = grid_search.predict(X_test)

print('Accuracy of NN on test is:',accuracy_score(y_test,nn_pred))
print("\n%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should compile your model before you put it into the pipeline.

```
scaler = StandardScaler()
model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(120, input_dim=46,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.1, noise_shape=None, seed=None))

model.add(Dense(80, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.1, noise_shape=None, seed=None))

model.add(Dense(40, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

pipeline = make_pipeline(scaler,model)
pipeline.fit(X_train,y_train, epochs=50, batch_size=20, validation_data = (X_test,y_test))

# evaluate the model
scores = pipeline.evaluate(X_test,y_test)
print("\n%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100))
```

Comment: I am getting again some exception "not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)"

Comment: Can you put your entire code leading up to this and a snippet of your data?